# IPFS url throws CSP error when trying to load iframe using forms.google

Tags: reactjs, iframe, google-forms, content-security-policy, ipfs

I'm working on creating an NFT minting dapp.  I'm trying to host it on IPFS.  However I'm running into some issues after deployment when accessing it from the IPFS gateway.

In my App, I have an Iframe setup like so:

```
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/{contentHash}/viewform?embedded=true" 
  className='newsletter-widget'>Loading…</iframe>
```

This form loads fine on localhost, and it loads fine from githubpages, however when I try to host it on IPFS I get an error:

> Refused to frame 'https://docs.google.com/' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Note that 'frame-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

How can I use Iframes on IPFS?

Hmm, this seems to be throwing because errors are thrown in the IFrame, Cloudflare's IPFS gateway renders fine and show the errors but other gateways don't work properly.

The error google found error is shown below:

> GET filesystem:https://docs.google.com/persistent/docs/fonts/KFOjCnqEu92Fr1Mu51TzBhc4AMP6lQ.woff2 net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Not sure why its requestion from `filesystem:`